# Performance of sum with mask vs. do-loop

Tags: performance, sum, fortran

Is the intrinsic function `sum` with masks slower than an old-school do-loop?

I am writing a program for a financial application in Fortran 90.
There is a user-defined-type, which lumps together some 50 properties of a 
single bond, like book-value, time-value, interest-rates, which are of atomic type integer, real and character.

```
type(portfolioElementType)
    real(8) :: timeValue
    real(8) :: bookValue
    real(8) :: maturityInYears
    + many, many more
end type
```

The whole portfolio consists of a 2-dimensional matrix with 3000 times 10 elements of type `portfolioElementType`

```
type(portfolioElementType), dimension(:,:), pointer :: portfolio
allocate(portfolio(1:3000,1:10))
```

I want to aggregate the portfolio by maturityInYears. In SQL you would call it a group-by-statement.

Currently it is done by

```
do bond = 1 to numberOfBonds
    do part = 1 to numberOfParts
        if (portfolio(bond,part)%maturity .eq. 10) then
            sum10Years = sum10Years + portfolio(bond,part)%bookValue
        end if
    end do 
end do
```

I would prefer for purely aesthetic reasons only to do it by:

```
sum10 = sum(portfolio%bookValue, mask = portfolio%maturity .eq. 10)
```

Booth options give the same result, but the sum-approach seems to be slower than the do-loop. This surprises me, because summing some 30 000 elements
should be almost effortless?

My hypothesis is, that the "large" user defined type is slowing things down.
I don't know how Fortran handles its memory structures, but I guess that the
"bookValues" are located "far" from each other in memory?

Do you think it advisable if I used a matrix of a "large" user-defined-datastructure compared to a user-defined-datastructure of "big" matrices in the sense:

```
portfolio(a,b)%bookValue versus 
bigPortfolio%bookValue(a,b)
```

with

```
type(bigPortfolio)
   real(8), dimension(1:3000,1:10), pointer :: bookValue
   ...many more matrices
end type
```

Comment: This is subject to optimization, and will therefore depend on the optimization level, compiler, its options, your machines, and so forth... But in general, it is my experience that compilers can optimize "simple codes" better than "complicated" ones. Furthermore, OOP typically requires a lot of (de-)referencing, which slows down the code.

Comment: Summing 30,000 elements perhaps should be almost effortless but making 30,000 reads of non-contiguous memory locations might not be as quick as reading 30,000 contiguous memory locations (as OP suggests).  This looks like a classic case of the choice between an *array of structures* and a *structure of arrays*.

Comment: And another thing, though it's unlikely to have a noticeable impact on performance ... unless you actually need pointers I'd use `allocatable` arrays these days.

Comment: @Ratilius, when you say 'the sum-approach seems to be slower than the do-loop', what order of time difference are you talking about? How did you time it? How many runs did you average to get to that conclusion?

Comment: I use gprof and the function using the sums suddenly is among the slowest functions. I compile using gcc with o3. The runtime rose from 73 seconds to 85 seconds (walltime-clock). The code snippet in question is only a tiny building block in a big program and should maybe account for 1 % of the runtime, because its not called very often. I will build a sandbox-example and and post it, if I can emulate that behaviour.